# accessing External Referrers with Facebook Graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

How do I go about accessing External Referrers? I see this information in the new Insights/Reach, but can't find it in the Graph API at all.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get them via the Graph API by querying into the FQL insights table.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

An example of one of the referrals I see there is `page_views_external_referrals`, however, there are dozens more listed on that documentation page.

Comment: I checked the Insights within the Graph API, and there are no totals whatsoever, only a few daily samples. Also, FQL is no good, as it's deprecated, I'm looking for this information in the Graph API.

Comment: FQL is not deprecated.  Insights from FQL are also not deprecated.  However there are some FQL insights columns that are being removed from FQL.  They are marked as such in the long list of items on that page.  I know, I got confused by it until I scrolled down to see ones being removed.    As far as totals, see the "Available Periods" column to see how facebook is totalling items.  For "page_views_external_referrals" it is a daily value.

Comment: well, blessed be you sir, I'm a SQL nut, so hearing that FQL is alive and well is a joyful thing indeed. A couple of you brought this distinction to me attention, thanks to you both.